# Bootstrap Collapse has a slight delay when you click to close it

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and using the collapse component to hide nested rows in my table. It works as you would expect except when you click to close the row there is a slight delay. I would expect the opening speed and the closing speed to match. How can I fix this? The arrows rotate in my local environment and they're not matching the speed of the collapse. Feel free to check out my `<table>` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfg2v0s9/6/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the animations BS uses. You can disable them:

```
$(function() { $.support.transition = false; })
```